# Install npm package with conda via environment.yml

Tags: python, node.js, npm, conda

I am wondering if it's possible to install npm packages directly through conda's `environment.yml` file. I know one can install `pypi` packages with `pip` directly as follows:

```
name: docs
channels:
  - conda-forge

dependencies:
  - python>=3.7
  - nodejs=10.*
  - pip
  - pip:
    - Sphinx==1.6.5
```

I've tried adding `npm` as a dependency as it's installed via `nodejs` but that doesn't work, unfortunately.

```
name: docs
channels:
  - conda-forge

dependencies:
  - python>=3.7
  - nodejs=10.*
  - pip
  - pip:
    - Sphinx==1.6.5
  - npm:
    - jsdoc
```

☝️ Doesn't work.

I know I can install `jsdoc` after installing the conda environment using `npm install -g jsdoc` but I am curious if there's a way to integrate the installation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the early days, [the idea of integrating other specialized package managers was floated](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/307), but I think [the problematic experience with `pip` integration](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/) has indicated that doing so would be a Herculean task.  It's not that setting up the installation mechanism would be hard, it's the safeguarding against the various package managers clobbering each other's packages. So, no it's not a thing and likely won't be for a while.

Alternatively, if one really needed to have an NPM package in an env (i.e., installed via the YAML), one could write a Conda package for it that depended on `nodejs` and simply did an `npm install` call in the build script.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I really appreciate the `pip` integration but I can imagine it getting hairy quickly when several package managers are involved.