# How to install CRAN packages in environment.yml

Tags: r, github, conda, cran

I'm using miniconda to manage my installation of data science packages. It is a workflow that I have somewhat established now, so I would like it to work in this case too. I also would assume it to work, since it is supposed to help in situations like this - where more dependencies than pure python is needed.

I would like to install the python [cdt toolbox](https://github.com/FenTechSolutions/CausalDiscoveryToolbox). It is a `pip`-installable package available on PyPI but not in any conda channels. It requires PyTorch, available easily in PyPI and in their own conda channel. But it further requires some r-packages, most available on CRAN and some only on github. My dream scenario is to have a single `environment.yml` file looking something like this:

```yaml
name: my_env
channels:
 - defaults
 - pytorch
dependencies:
 - pytorch
 - cpuonly
 - pip
 - pip:
   - cdt
   - -e .
 - r:         # this line and below don't work...
   - pcalg    # available on CRAN, but not in conda channel r
   - kpcalg   # available on CRAN, but not in conda channel r
   - github:https://github.com/Diviyan-Kalainathan/RCIT # R package not in CRAN nor on conda
```

I assume there is not a simple direct way to do it like above, based on [this question on SO about similar npm installs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57082949/install-npm-package-with-conda-via-environment-yml). I cannot possibly be the first persion with a need to install both r and python packages... so what is the 'standard' workarounds?

Comment: There is no special directive for R package installation. `pip` is sort of exceptional as per that other post. The canonical answer is to create Conda packages for what is not already there. The `pcalg` package is already available through the **bioconda** channel (under the name `r-pcalg`). It should be straightforward to add `kpcalg` to Bioconda - all its dependencies are already hosted there or on Conda Forge. The RCIT package only has standard dependencies, so you could possible build a Conda Forge recipe for it.