# Create a conda environment from a YAML file with perl packages

Tags: perl, conda

I´m working on Ubuntu. I´ve created a pipeline that needs to have a conda environment with some Python packages and Perl5 with some packages.

I got the python packages and Perl5 via conda and installed the Perl packages with [perl-app-cpanminus](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/perl-app-cpanminus) a conda package.

Now I did like to distribute my pipeline to other people and want to give them as less preparation time as possible to run it, therefore I want to save and export the environment file as YAML. I know how to do this with conda packages but I was wondering if I could in any way include the Perl packages too?
Like you do with pip for example:

```
channels:
  - bioconda
  - conda-forge
  - anaconda
dependencies:
  - pandas
  - pip:
      - pip_package1
      - pip_package2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a Conda package, then it would be another dependency.

```yaml
channels:
  - bioconda
  - conda-forge
  - anaconda
dependencies:
  - python=3.10  # always specify a Python version (through minor)

  ## Conda Python pacakges
  - pandas
  
  ## PyPI Python packages
  ## note: only use if not available through Conda
  #- pip:
  #    - pip_package1
  #    - pip_package2

  ## Perl packages
  - perl-app-cpanminus
```

Otherwise, Pip is a special case - Conda does not have any direct support for side-loading via other package managers. This is discussed a bit in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57098581/570918).

Comment: I kinda feared that there would be no simple way^^. But now I can be sure, thank you :) I´m probably gonna try to write a shell script that installs all Perl packages at the beginning of my pipeline.

Comment: @snakelake better would be to add them to Conda Forge (if generic) or Bioconda (if domain-specific). At the very least, *request* that those packages be added on the respective issue queues ([Bioconda](https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/issues) or [Conda Forge](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/issues)). That helps the maintainers know what the community requires, and having a mode of package installation should help simplify reproducibility.